# Using HSDPA modem on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hsdpa

I usally don't like the software (not the drivers, the other stuff) that hardware manufactorers bundle with their hardware. Now I have a build in HSDPA modem in my DELL notebook.

Can I configure a connection only with Windows 7's own connection manager (and how)? Or do I have to install/use the Broadband-something-Manager tool from DELL?

Help and links are apreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is, how it goes:

1. If you have installed the Mobile Broadband Manager from DELL, deinstall it.
2. Get the latest version of the DRIVER for your Modem and install it.
3. Click on the network icon (shows a computer or five bars) on the lower right.
4. Click on your provider name and click connect.
5. If your SIM card has a PIN you will be asked for it now.

Connection established.